# Pug - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to  display all posts in my database via the `getList` function:

In my service layer I have the following function:

```
function getList() {
        const res = knex('posts').where({
            deleted: false,
        }).orderBy('createdAt')
        console.log("getList: " + res)
        return res
    }
```

Within the route file I am calling my `getList` function:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const service = require('../services/post')

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  postList = service.getList().then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
  console.log("Postlist: " + postList)

  res.render('index', {
    postList: postList
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Finally I would like to display the result in my `index.pug` file:

```
  table.table
    thead.thead-inverse
      tr
        th #
        th Title
        th Description  
        th Created At
        th Action
    tbody
      //TODO: If post is empty
      for post in postList
        tr
          td(scope='row')=post.id
          td=post.title
          td=post.description
          td=post.createdAt
          td
            a.btn.btn-primary(href='/edit', role='button') Edit
```

However, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\views\index.pug:22 20| for post in postList 21| tr > 22| td(scope='row')=post.id 23| td=post.title 24| td=post.description 25| td=post.createdAt Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

TypeError: C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\views\index.pug:22
    20|       for post in postList
    21|         tr
  > 22|           td(scope='row')=post.id
    23|           td=post.title
    24|           td=post.description
    25|           td=post.createdAt
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at eval (eval at wrap (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:152:61)
    at eval (eval at wrap (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:173:4)
    at template (eval at wrap (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:225:119)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:428:38)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:418:21)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:465:11)
    at View.render (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:127:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:971:7)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\routes\index.js:10:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
```

Furthermore I get the following console output:

```
Listening on localhost:8080
getList: select * from "posts" where "deleted" = false order by "createdAt" asc
Postlist: [object Promise]
GET / 500 326.920 ms - 4255
[{"id":6,"title":"Excepturi rerum ratione omnis aut quo.","description":"Eum nostrum vel reiciendis qui. Nam sapiente unde deserunt totam at dolores. Tempor
e corrupti fugiat et consequuntur vero. Laboriosam autem mollitia odit cum repellat.","deleted":false,"createdAt":"2017-09-17T01:15:31.865Z","updatedAt":"20
17-09-16T22:02:41.233Z","deletedAt":"2017-09-17T00:02:15.235Z"}]
GET /css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css 304 3.464 ms - -
GET /css/style.css 304 0.913 ms - -
GET /js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js 304 1.173 ms - -
```

Is there a problem within my pug file? Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE**

I changed my router to the following and it works:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  knex('posts').select().where({
    deleted: false,
  }).orderBy('createdAt').then(query => {
    res.render('index', {
      postList: query
    }); 
  })
});
```

Any suggestions why?

Comment: are you getting anything in `console.log("Postlist: " + postList)`?

Comment: @RaghavGarg Please see my updated post

Comment: try the keyword `each` instead of `for` like: `each post in postList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pug js, you do the loop using `each`. So you would have to do something like:

```
each post in postList
```

Read more about [Pug each](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html#each)

or you can use for loop like:

```
- for (post in postList) {
    // pug code in between
- }
```

Reference: https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#unbuffered-code

### Update

Your previous code has one problem, you are making an async request so you need to write the code inside of `then` of the promise returning form the funciton `getList`. So need to change your code to:

```
service.getList().then(data => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    res.render('index', {
        postList: data
    });
})
```

Comment: Thx for your reply! I still get the error `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`. It seems to me that I do not get the data correctly and push it into the frontend. Is there probably anything wrong with my router?

Comment: I changed my router and now it works. However, I am not sure why? Any suggestions? Please see my update.

Comment: @mrquad, please see the updated answer, and if the answer helped you then please consider accepting it.